# Android application force closes after adding SQL Lite codes

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm having a problem with the SQL Lite for my phone model is  LG Optimus One P500. my phone android version is updated from FroYo to Gingerbread and update works fine on me. My app also works fine on other phone models.

Application works at first and also shows my main page but when I start the game the problem then appears and then force closes my app.

Database creation (initialization) activity begins after the score page will show so I think the problem should not exists after I start the game but after all this problem only started when I added my database codes.

For better understanding my activity goes like this:

1. Get name at the startup then stores the name in a String variable
   after start button is pressed. (My problem then exists on this part)
2. I have a timer and score text in my second Layout this will be fetched later after the game is finished.
3. The database will now be created(if not yet exists) and those 3 data will then be stored in the database.

Here's my database code (I just get it from a tutorial from the web):

```
public class DataHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "scores.db";
       private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
       private static final String TABLE_NAME = "tblScores";

       private Context context;
       private SQLiteDatabase db;

       private SQLiteStatement insertStmt;
       private static final String INSERT = "insert into "
          + TABLE_NAME + "(name,score,time) values (?,?,?)";

       public DataHelper(Context context) {
              this.context = context;
              OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context);
              this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
              this.insertStmt = this.db.compileStatement(INSERT);
           }

       public long insert(String name, String score, String time) {
          this.insertStmt.bindString(1, name);
          this.insertStmt.bindString(2, score); 
          this.insertStmt.bindString(3, time);
          return this.insertStmt.executeInsert();
       }

       public void deleteAll() {
          this.db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
       }

       public List<String> selectAll() {
              List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
              Cursor cursor = this.db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "name","score","time" },
                /*"name in ('A','B')"*/ null, null, /*"name"*/null, null, "score, time desc");
              if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                 do {
                    list.add(cursor.getString(0)+" "+cursor.getString(1)+" "+cursor.getString(2));
                    //list.add(cursor.getString(1));
                 } while (cursor.moveToNext());
              }
              if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                 cursor.close();
              }
              return list;
           }

       private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

          OpenHelper(Context context) {
             super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
          }

          @Override
          public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
             db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, score TEXT, time TEXT)");
          }

          @Override
          public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
             Log.w("Example", "Upgrading database, this will drop tables and recreate.");
             db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
             onCreate(db);
          }
       }
    }
```

Here's the log file from my phone:

```
[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=arc.android.memorygame/.Ma
inActivity } from pid 1875
D/PhoneWindow( 1875): <!>com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow 1472<!> co
uldn't save which view has focus because the focused view com.jiubang.ggheart.ap
ps.desks.appfunc.XViewFrame@40675e08 has no id.
I/ActivityManager( 1573): Start proc arc.android.memorygame for activity arc.and
roid.memorygame/.MainActivity: pid=12927 uid=10098 gids={1015}
I/ggheart ( 1875): <!>fs 742<!> onStop
I/wpa_supplicant( 1731): wpa_supplicant_get_scan_results: Start
I/wpa_supplicant( 1731): CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS  Ready
I/wpa_supplicant( 1731): wpa_supplicant_event_scan_results: ap_scan 1,  disconne
cted 0
I/wpa_supplicant( 1731): No suitable AP found.
I/wpa_supplicant( 1731): Setting scan request: 20 sec 0 usec
I/dun_service( 1481): process rmnet event
I/dun_service( 1481):  rstate == DUN_RMNETSTATE_ERROR in dun_monitor_kevents
V/WifiMonitor( 1573): <!>android.net.wifi.WifiMonitor$MonitorThread 176<!> Event
 [Setting scan request: 20 sec 0 usec]
I/#LGIME  ( 1671): <!>com.jungle.android.utils.Glog 32<!> #### onStartInput: res
tarting=false, fieldId=2131099699
I/ActivityManager( 1573): <!>com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord 444<!> Display
ed arc.android.memorygame/.MainActivity: +1s490ms
D/StatusBarPolicy( 1657): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 1
D/StatusBarPolicy( 1657): [BRIGHTHY] curNetwork=51502 curHPLMN=51502
E/dalvikvm-heap(12927): 9850880-byte external allocation too large for this proc
ess.
E/GraphicsJNI(12927): VM won't let us allocate 9850880 bytes
D/skia    (12927): --- decoder->decode returned false
W/dalvikvm(12927): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4
0018560)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(12927): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2:
 Error inflating class <unknown>
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(Layout
Inflater.java:518)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutI
nflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag
(LayoutInflater.java:568)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInf
later.java:386)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInf
later.java:320)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInf
later.java:276)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.
setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.
java:1657)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at arc.android.memorygame.MainActivity.startGame
(MainActivity.java:194)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at arc.android.memorygame.MainActivity$1.onClick
(MainActivity.java:108)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485
)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:
9080)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.jav
a:587)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.ja
va:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThrea
d.java:3729)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:5
07)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndA
rgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:874)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Zygot
eInit.java:632)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(12927): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative
(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Con
structor.java:415)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(Layout
Inflater.java:505)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        ... 20 more
E/AndroidRuntime(12927): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exce
eds VM budget
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAs
set(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(B
itmapFactory.java:460)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource
Stream(BitmapFactory.java:336)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFrom
ResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Re
sources.java:1709)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(Ty
pedArray.java:601)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1951)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1899)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:
286)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayo
ut.java:120)
E/AndroidRuntime(12927):        ... 23 more
W/ActivityManager( 1573):   Force finishing activity arc.android.memorygame/.Mai
nActivity
W/ActivityManager( 1573): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{4070d4e8 arc.
android.memorygame/.MainActivity}
I/DemoService( 1875): <!>fs 730<!> DiyScheduer.onStart
I/ggheart ( 1875): <!>fs 732<!> onStart
I/ActivityManager( 1573): No longer want com.viber.voip:keepAliveReceiver (pid 2
474): hidden #16
D/StatusBarPolicy( 1657): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 1
D/StatusBarPolicy( 1657): [BRIGHTHY] curNetwork=51502 curHPLMN=51502
I/#LGIME  ( 1671): <!>com.jungle.android.utils.Glog 32<!> #### onStartInput: res
tarting=false, fieldId=-1
I/ActivityManager( 1573): Process arc.android.memorygame (pid 12927) has died.
```

Also, anyone can help me in querying in Java? I'm quite a newbie in this one. As you see I'm just editing then testing the query commands. A detailed view on how this works will be fine.

Comment: can you post a stacktrace of the crash so we know what is causing it?

Comment: I can't, as you see the problem only occurs on my phone while it works fine on other phones. It also works fine when I deployed it on my emulator. I work on it using Android 2.2 Version emulator and deployed it on a 2.2 and 2.3 version phones which all works fine except on my phone which is a 2.3 updated version.

Comment: You can still view the logcat. Just use `adb -d logcat` to view the logs from the device. Make sure your device is connected to the computer and turn on USB debugging in your phone.

Comment: Got it! Will post the log together with my question. Thanks Aki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. the exception is in there - OutOfMemoryError while inflating a bitmap

Comment: Yes it appears that it is the main reason but I wonder why does it only happens after I added the database activity while my first release works just fine?

Comment: Probably because it was maginal before and the extra overhead of the dataase tipped it over the edge.

Comment: I see, well any solution for this?

Comment: It's an OutOfMemoryError. Either tweak your VM to give more memory to the app (do you want your users to do that too?) or try to use less resources.